# Entity Framework 6 Exception not caught

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I accidently forgot to provide the correct Linq statement and compiled, run the project. And stumbled upon a very curious behaviour.

I would expect to get an exception thrown by this code, but instead, it is handed as a result of the method. Meaning, the exception is attached to the returned value from my "GetAllProducts" method.

Here's my sample code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            return ctx.Products.Select(p => new Product { });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new MySpecificException(e);
    }
}
```

If anybody can explain this sort of behaviour I would sleep happy :)

Answer (score 5):

`.Select` is a deferred operation - it doesn't actually query or collect records anything until you enumerate the `IEnumerable<T>` You should return something from `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`. Those actually cause the `IEnumerable<T>` (or technically `IQueryable<T>`) to enumerate.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your quick answer. But I was more concerned actually about the exception not being cought at all.

Comment: @wiwi its because the enumeration is happening outside of `GetAllProducts` control.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on where to catch this kind of exception if any .. I mean like a global EF exception handler?

Comment: @wiwi i'm not sure - that would be a new question post.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification on the deferred behaviour. I'll try to open a wider question on the global exception handling if I don't find any explicit reply on SO

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, no exception is returned by this method, nor is there an exception attached to the return value of this method.  What this method returns is an `IEnumerable<Product>`, which can be enumerated, but has not yet been enumerated.  To 'enumerate' is to go through a collection of things and do something with each thing in the collection.

When the `GetAllProducts` method returns, the database has not yet been touched, but an `IEnumerable<Product>` is returned that will try to query the database when the `IEnumerable<Product>` is enumerated.

If you want to catch the exception you are seeing, add a `try`/`catch` block around the code that ends up enumerating the `IEnumerable<Product>`, like this:

```
var products = GetAllProducts();
try
{
    foreach(var product in products)  // Enumeration happens here, exception thrown
    {
        // do something with each product
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate more on the topic :)

Comment: And to be completely fair, I saw the Exception attached to the "products" result on the "Results View" while debugging. And this enumerates the IEnumerable indeed. So may be I need to trigger this enumeration in the DAL layer to be able to throw a DAL Exception to my consuming API (this was my initial goal in fact)

Comment: If you want to trigger the exception without actually using the data, you can force the enumeration by calling `ToList()`, as suggested by Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the input CodeThug :)